# MDX , Calculate Number of days when the cummulative sum of Revenues from end of a month date match with the given debt amount

Tags: mdx

I have a financial cube and i have to calculate Daily Sales Outstanding as :

Number of Days between the selected month last date and the earliest transaction date when cummulative sum of Revenue from last date of the month till the date where sum revenue <= the debt amount for the date .

e.g

On 31/12/2009 my debt amount = 2,500,000

```
                          31-Dec-09     30-Nov-09    15-Oct-09     31-Oct-09
```

Revenue                       1,000,000     1,000,000    500,000          1,0000

Cummulative sum of revenue    1,000,000     2,00,000     2,500,000      4,000,000

No of Days                      31            30                 16

On 15/Oct/09 cummulative revenue is 2,500,000 which equals my debt amount on that day

Count of Days = 31 + 31 + 16 = 76 Days.

In other words Sum Revenue from the selected date backwards until sum total equals or exeeds the total to date balance of the debtors.

Any help will be highly appreciated .

If i haven't explained clearly enough or if you need more information then please let me know.

Thanks in advance .

Shuchi.

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined this blog: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/christianwade/archive/2006/04/30/MDX-Sprocs-and-Scripting_3A00_-An-Interesting-Example.aspx

He covers a few ways of approaching this, it sounds to me like a recursive problem, in that you need to 'walk backwards up along the calendar' adding up revenue, until you find the day where the added up revenue meets/exceeds the initial debt?

The above link should give you a few different approaches to tackle this, shout if you get  stuck.